# How to find & remove space from a column value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have table and there is one field where i store huge html document. each html document has many url. by mistake when html data was inserted into table then there was some space stored in url like

```
www.mysite.com/content.aspx?id=audi 2000 
rather it should be  www.mysite.com/content.aspx?id=audi2000
```

so when user click on the link then no page is showing. there are huge data is stored with same space problem in url. so just guide me which sql query i should use to remove those space as result my url should look like

```
www.mysite.com/content.aspx?id=audi2000 or
www.mysite.com/ content.aspx?id=audi2000 it should www.mysite.com/content.aspx?id=audi2000
```

so just guide me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

you could use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
replace(yourcolumn, ' ', '')
```

eg:

```
update tableName set columnName = Replace(columnName,' ','') -- where id = 2595
```

Comment: basically huge text will store with space and url. i just need to find out all links from column and if url has space then i need to replace with no space.so guide me how to extract all hyperlink from data and check if there is space in href portion that i need to remove.

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048705/how-to-find-replace-space-from-hyperlink-src-attribute-sql-server

Comment: @Thomas oh, then that's quite another problem... Could you show a sample ? Because I feel it might be really hard to see where is the end of an url if url can have spaces !