# How to find & replace space from hyperlink src attribute SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

i have table and there is one field where i store huge html data. each html data has many url & lots of other text. by mistake when html data was inserted into table then there was some space stored in hyperlink src attribute like below way

```
http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=Alfa_Romeo_164_1991_LCD_Climate_Control_it
http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=Audi_A6_2001_Brake_Calliper_it
http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=audi_a4_amp_a6_1996_2001_and_vw_passat_1996_2001_abs_pumps_commonly_failing_it
http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=Audi_A2_Body_control_failure_it
http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=Audi_A4_1997_Heater_Control_Unit_it
```

just see **%20** means space.

```
actually url should stored in like this way without space
 http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?content=Alfa_Romeo_164_1991_LCD_Climate_Control_it
```

i want to find space from every url and replace with no space. thanks

### update here is my data

```
<p align="left" class="MsoNormal" style="LINE-HEIGHT: normal"><span lang="IT" style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Centraline Climatizzatore<br></span><span style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman','serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"><a href="http://www.bba-reman.com/content.aspx?content=Alfa_147_JTD_2005_Climate_Control_it"><font size="2" face="Arial">Alfa Romeo 147 JTD 2005 - Unità centralina climatizzatore (Numero di pezzo 7353377750) </font></a></span><span lang="IT" style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman','serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"><br></span><span style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman','serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"><a href="http://www.bba-reman.com/content.aspx? content=Alfa_Romeo_164_1991_LCD_Climate_Control_it"><span lang="IT" style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Alfa Romeo 164 Early 90s - Guasto centralina Climatizzatore LCD.</span></a></span><span lang="IT" style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times  New Roman','serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"><br></span><span style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman','serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"><a href="http://www.bba-reman.com/content.aspx?content=Alfa-Romeo-156-16v-ABS-0273004535-italia"><span lang="IT" style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans- serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Alfa Romeo 156 L'unità centralina climatizzatore non rimane alla temperatura stabilita</span></a></span></p>
```

Comment: can you please give whole row data or atleast a tag with SRC attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note this is a quick and dirty, needs more testing**

There is probably a much more graceful way of doing this, but try...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Url, 0, PATINDEX('%[%20]%', @Url)) + SUBSTRING(@Url, PATINDEX('%[%20]%', @Url) + 3, LEN(@Url) - PATINDEX('%[%20]%', @Url) + 2);
```

Which can be tested using:

```
DECLARE @Url nvarchar(100) = 'http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=Alfa_Romeo_164_1991_LCD_Climate_Control_it';

SELECT @Url;

SELECT PATINDEX('%20%', @Url);

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Url, 0, PATINDEX('%[%20]%', @Url)) + SUBSTRING(@Url, PATINDEX('%[%20]%', @Url) + 3, LEN(@Url) - PATINDEX('%[%20]%', @Url) + 2);
```

**EDIT**

Here is a slightly less dirty approach. Just stick your pattern between the squared brackets.

```
DECLARE @Url nvarchar(100) = 'mysite.com/content.aspx? content=Alf-romeo';
DECLARE @Pattern nvarchar(100) = '[ ]';
DECLARE @Len int = 0;

SELECT @Url;
SELECT LEN(@Pattern);

IF LEFT(@Pattern, 1) = '[' AND RIGHT(@Pattern, 1) = ']' BEGIN
    SELECT @Len = (LEN(@Pattern) - 2);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Len = LEN(@Pattern);
END

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Url, 0, PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Url)) + SUBSTRING(@Url, PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Url) + @Len, LEN(@Url) - PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Url) + @Len);
```

Comment: how to mention a space in PATINDEX ? actually there is space in url like http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx? content=Alf-romeo. your answer looks promising and i will mark it as answer. thanks

Comment: i update my question with chunk of real data where u find space in src attribute like "content.aspx? content=Alfa_Romeo_164" i need to remote the space after all content.aspx? . i check the patindex but it did not work for space.

Comment: Replace the '%20' with a space ' ' like so.... `SELECT SUBSTRING(@Url, 0, PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @Url)) + SUBSTRING(@Url, PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @Url) + 1, LEN(@Url) - PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @Url) + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to give you a **correct** answer to this problem without looking at your data closely to understand how it's structured.
How was the html created? By hand? With a WYSIWYG designer that chucks in tons of markup?
The problem is that the **correct** way to do this is slow - you have to load every html document - row by row - into a DOM parser & use the DOM to edit the links.
The faster way would be to use regular expressions but that depends on you having a good understanding of the html layout & it having a relatively clean format that suits a regex.
But google html regex parser & most advice will be to use the DOM method. That's because writing your own html parser as a regex is not simple - html is not a simple standard. If there are uncommon html features in your code, the regex will mess it up beyond repair.
If all URLs to replace start with *http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content* that's doable with

```
UPDATE docs
SET html=REPLACE(html,'http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?%20content=','http://www.mysite.com/content.aspx?content=')
```

(assuming your table is named [docs] & the field to change is [html])

Comment: i update my question with chunk of real data where u find space in src attribute like "content.aspx? content=Alfa_Romeo_164" i need to remote the space after all content.aspx? . i check the patindex but it did not work for space